How to calculate mean CPU and memory usage of a command line?
The following command in UNIX:
time sh -c julia src/script_etudedtsi.jl 80 20 100 366 5 10 0 1 0 0 1 1

returned the elapsed time for my Julia script.
I tried:
pidstat -u -p $(pgrep -f julia src/script_etudedtsi.jl 80 20 100 366 5 10 0 1 0 0 1 1) 1
pgrep: only one pattern can be provided

How could I get the mean CPU and memory usage for the same command during the elapsed time?

While the content may imply an OS, you don't actually specify which OS this is regarding. Please edit this post and add the specific OS and shell you're working in.

@music2myear It's obvious from command usage it's a *nix environment.

@music2myear, I have changed the question thanks to you :)

The time command can give a way to generate basic stats.
time -v your_command

After running, time will show the "User" and "Sys" times, representing the CPU time used by the program. Do this a number of times. Calculate the "mean" CPU usage by averaging.  Sum up your values, then divide by the number of CPU cores.
For memory usage, time outputs "maximum resident set size", which gives the "peak usage" in kilobytes.  Average the values.  If you want bytes, multiply the total by 1024.
You could use ps with bash scripts to do the polling:
Create run_command.sh with the following:
#!/bin/bash

"$@" &
pid=$!
echo $pid > /tmp/command.pid
wait $pid
rm /tmp/command.pid

Make executable: chmod +x run_command.sh
Create calc_mean_usage.sh with:
#!/bin/bash

show_help() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [OPTION]... COMMAND"
    echo "Calculate mean CPU and memory usage."
    echo "    --help                       Shows this help"
    echo "    --log=[file]                 Log polling intervals"
    echo "    --show                       Output to console"
    exit 1
}

log_file=""
show_output=false

# Parse options
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        --help)
            show_help
            ;;
        --log=*)
            log_file="${1#*=}"
            shift
            ;;
        --show)
            show_output=true
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    show_help
fi

# Assign the command to an array
your_command=("$@")

# Run the wrapper and capture PID to a file
./run_command.sh "${your_command[@]}" &

# Wait for file creation and read the PID
while [ ! -f /tmp/command.pid ]; do
    sleep 0.1
done
pid=$(cat /tmp/command.pid)

samples=0
interval=1

# Initialize data arrays
cpu_usages=()
mem_usages=()

# Collect CPU and memory usage samples for duration
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
    cpu_usage=$(ps -o %cpu= -p $pid)
    mem_usage=$(ps -o %mem= -p $pid)

    cpu_usages+=($cpu_usage)
    mem_usages+=($mem_usage)

    if $show_output; then
        echo "CPU Usage: $cpu_usage%, Memory Usage: $mem_usage%"
    fi

    if [ -n "$log_file" ]; then
        echo "CPU Usage: $cpu_usage%, Memory Usage: $mem_usage%" >> "$log_file"
    fi

    sleep $interval
    samples=$((samples + 1))
done

# Calculate mean CPU and memory usage
total_cpu=0
total_mem=0

for cpu in "${cpu_usages[@]}"; do
    total_cpu=$(echo "$total_cpu + $cpu" | bc)
done

for mem in "${mem_usages[@]}"; do
    total_mem=$(echo "$total_mem + $mem" | bc)
done

mean_cpu=$(echo "scale=2; $total_cpu / $samples" | bc)
mean_mem=$(echo "scale=2; $total_mem / $samples" | bc)

echo "Mean CPU Usage: $mean_cpu%, Mean Memory Usage: $mean_mem%"

exit 0

Usage:
./calc_mean_usage.sh bash -c "julia src/script_etudedtsi.jl 80 20 100 366 5 10 0 1 0 0 1 1"
This runs your_command in the background and polls every second, for the entire runtime of your_command, and will output CPU and memory usage each second, then calculates the mean values.
This way you can set any polling interval and not be worried about it stopping.

Thank you, it almost works. I ran it and it output: ./script_meanCPUMemory.sh: ligne 6: julia ./src/script_etudedtsi.jl 80 20 100 366 5 10 0 1 0 0 1 1: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % CPU Usage: %, Memory Usage: % Mean CPU Usage: 0%, Mean Memory Usage: 0%
"Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type" is French

"Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type" is French for no such file or directory. Please note that I do have execute rights for folder src and script_etudedtsi.jl
ls -al src returns -rwxr-xr-x 1 MyUserName MyUserName  1074 juil.  9 17:15 script_etudedtsi.jl

@JKHA I added the array notation ("$@"), all arguments should be correctly passed now.

@JayCravens, thank you for your updated answer, it still returns the same error though, after adding the array notation. At line 7 instead of previously line 6. Also, another remark I have, what if I do not know in advance the duration of my command? As sample=10 and interval=1, this is the average for the first 10s. I only know my command will last at minimum 5 minutes, but I have no exact upperbound on how long it could last (several hours ?)

@JoepvanSteen, yes I won't forget when all will be resolved, I promise :)

@JKHA Updated the post.  Give that a try.

@JayCravens, I have found the problem, we were missing bash -c in the usage of the command :) Thank you a lot for your help the command works very well :)

@JKHA Anytime, my friend. Glad to help.

@JayCravens, so now that the command works, how can I adjust Interval and Sample if I do not know in advance how long my command will last (see previous comment)?

@JKHA Hopefully a wrapper will solve any of those issues.

@JayCravens, you might be very much interested by this question

@JayCravens, it looks like the wrapper doesn't work. For instance :$ ./script_meanCPUMemory.sh bash -c "sleep 1" never ends! I am sorry I did not spotted this before selecting your answer

@JKHA It was missing an & at the end of ./run_command.sh "${your_command[@]}"  I've tested it with bash -c "sleep 1" and it ends properly now. :-)

@JayCravens, thanks so much, it works again :) Just a little minor patch, do you think you could avoid printing the value during the wrapper, (CPU Usage:  100%, Memory Usage:  0.5%) and only at the end, or make it optionnal? Because it pollutes the output console too much as the command I am running already prints a lot of info! Finally, I believe that you could create a little GitHub project for your wrapper if this doesn't exist yet and if you'd like it. I will star (favorite it) it for sure :)

@JayCravens, you helped me a lot :D I decided that I am giving you 50 of my reputation with a bounty to acknowledge you <3

@JKHA Well thank you, my friend!  Since you seemed truly interested in it, I have changed the behavior like you've requested, plus the option to show the output, log to file, or both.  I can certainly throw it on my github for you as well, no problem.

@JayCravens, it works perfectly, thanks :)
